# ReactNative App works on Simulator but crashes in TestFlight

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo, react-navigation, testflight

I am developing a ReactNative app for iOS using Expo.

The app worked correctly on a real iPhone with just basic components (View, Text, Button & Styling).

However, I added Stack Navigation last night.  The app had no issues on the simulator so I built through 'eas build' (also no problems). I submitted it to TestFlight for internal testing. But, when I click to open the app, it crashes immediately. As it is an actual app, it gives no info about the cause.

I am very stumped, so any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved this months ago but forgot to post the solution.

In case anyone is having a similair issue, the problem was really small.

I was using navigation components such as'createStackNavigator' instead of their native counterparts e.g. 'createNativeStackNavigator'. Made the swap and the app is now working properly.